# How to treat junk questions from users of less than 20 reputation?

Tags: discussion

Many questions asked by new users are good but many are not. Quite a few are junk. How to treat junk questions from users of less than 20 reputation remains unclear to me. Experience suggests that many such users are uninvested in the site and, therefore, presumably, undeterred by downvotes and the like.

Some such users style their questions without capitals or standard punctuation, as they were texting SMS messages to their teenaged pals. (Among these, incidentally, are too many who want us to do their beginning homework exercises for them.)

Many such questions are asked. One would rather not single out a particular example but examples are easy to find. Such questions are posted every quarter hour.

One wishes to be welcoming. Indeed, some new users are great. However, to welcome other new users who invest nothing, new users only want to use us, wastes too much of our time. It does not earn us many reputation points, either, so it just isn't much fun.

Seen in this light, what would be the most productive, time-efficient, community-building way to treat junk questions from users of less than 20 reputation?

Comment: The same way you treat junk questions from 20kers or 1 rep or Skeet.

Comment: If anything, you should try to provide more help and guidance for these new users than for high-rep users. Low-rep users might benefit from links to the help center, with high-rep users usually all that's left is a downvote and a close vote since they know the site well enough themselves.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: I get it. However, this assumes that the new user in question is willing and able to be helped. Many new users don't care, and why should they? This isn't their site. They are not invested. I wasn't complaining about new users, though, but asking for practical suggestions as to how to handle them as a population. In view of the direction in which my downvotes are headed, my question does not seem to be well received. Oh, well. The question makes sense to me, at any rate.

Comment: Well, I assume any user that invests some effort in asking a question does so in the hope to get help, else why would they do it? They may not have invested much effort, but only visiting the site, creating an account, and copy-pasting a homework question does take effort. But it also takes very little help to say: this question is off-topic here, please read `[ask]` and `[on-topic]`, so I think you can at least provide something like that.

Comment: Don't worry about their newness or worry that they'll feel unwelcome. As long as you treat the question as you would any other, you'll be fine. SO is not a good place for newbies to ask questions, **by design**. I just wish the introduction was clearer about that. SO's purpose is to  develop a set of excellent questions and answers for future reference.

Comment: [A good example of what to do with new user posts that don't meet our standards](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379649/why-wont-so-let-me-ask-a-question-about-how-i-cant-i-use-the-gtk-headers-to-dr)

Comment: @fbueckert you delete them? I was of the opinion we don't moderate users.

Comment: @Gimby We don't.  We moderate posts.  The question was not deleted when I commented, but was heavily downvoted.

Answer (score 28):

Why are you looking at questions?  To answer them?  To learn from them?  Or something else entirely?

And now here's the real question: **Why does who posted it matter?**

Treat each post independently of the poster.  If it's bad, downvote.  If it meets the criteria for closure, vote or flag to close.  If it's good, upvote it.  If you see something that doesn't look quite right, and you feel like it, edit it.  You're not doing it primarily as feedback to the poster.  It's feedback for *future readers*, so they know what's good and what's not.

Comment: Who has posted the question does matter very much as such. However, some questions waste one's time and some do not. My observation has been that questions posted by users of 1000 rep seldom waste my time. What has your observation been? Put another way, is there any limit to the number of low-quality questions *by uninvested users* you are willing to handle?

Comment: I think your perspective has some merit, but it needs to be tempered with our overall goal here.  Yeah, the vast majority of 1 rep users won't be posting good content.  Nobody's saying you have to spend any time helping them; if it's not good, downvote, flag, close, delete, whatever, and move on.  It's all volunteer effort, so we don't want to force anyone to do anything they don't want to.

Comment: @thb My observation has been that the higher the question author's rep the less likely the question is to be useful, since you asked.  Higher reputation users are also very unlikely to care about the rep loss from downvotes, as it's just *so much* less than what an upvote gives.  In fact, a low rep users generally has *much more* to lose from a downvote than a higher rep user (as the low rep user has a shot at being post banned).

Comment: @thb If you have some suggestion as to how to prevent people from posting low quality questions (that doesn't inhibit quality questions from being posed) they by all means, *suggest it*.  There are already quite a lot of mechanisms in place, and a lot of time and effort has been spent on them.  But if you have an idea for something better, by all means, propose it.  But it's not at all an easy problem, hence why the existing solutions are so fallible, so make sure your suggestions aren't already in place, and that they don't have major problems or averse side effects before posting them.

Comment: @servy I do not have a suggestion. After six years on the site, I do not know the answer. This is why I have asked. For new users who actually care about their rep, you are right, but I observe a large population of new users—probably one-time users—who do not need to care about their rep because they just want someone to do their homework for them, or whatever. I am that way, too. On, say, Reddit, I hardly care if you downvote me, because I do not happen to be a habitual Reddit user. I was speaking of the many, many users to whom reputation points were never valuable in the first place.

Comment: @thb There's no point in asking the question if  you have nothing to propose.   If someone else comes up with an idea for how to improve the quality of the questions on this site, they can write their own proposal, they don't need this question here.  Yes, there are lots of people that don't care about their rep.  In fact, it's *almost everyone*.   I don't care about my rep, nor do most other high rep users.  *Very* few people are dettered by specifically the rep-loss aspect of downvotes.  This is not something new.

Comment: @thb: "*is there any limit to the number of low-quality questions by uninvested users you are willing to handle?*" I find the focus of your question to be missing the point. I *don't care* if a low quality question comes from "uninvested users" or "invested users". I care that it is a low quality question, *period*. You are too focused on who is asking the question, and not focused enough on the question *itself*. Let the question stand or fall on its own merits.

Comment: It seems that my question has been answered. As for me, I remain slightly skeptical, for I doubt that the answer scales and prefer systems that complement (rather than deny) human nature, but that's just me. In case anyone still cares, my earlier comment, which I can no longer edit, inadvertently dropped a word: "Who has posted the question does [not] matter very much as such." In any case, I thank you for the discussion.

Comment: @thb The personal element matters in some situations; chat and comments, namely; we don't have to be rude.  But when it comes to the content, nothing else matters.  Who posted it is irrelevant to building the repository of knowledge.  We don't change how we curate because it was asked by someone with 100k rep, or 1 rep.  A bad question is a bad question is a bad question.